# In PowerPoint, can I edit/design a slide from a certain point in the animation timeline onward?

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

When working with animations in PowerPoint it can easily get overcrowded, especially when a few objects are on top of one another and supposed to reveal/exit one after the other.

And, in my case, I have a picture that will start to travel along a motion path and when it ends I want to put arrows pointing to parts of it.

However when I want to align the arrows properly I can't see where exactly the picture will end up. I can see a faded preview when I select the motion path but as soon as I click off it, it disappears.

Is there a way to set the slide, while in "design mode", to a certain point in the animation timeline, so the picture would have moved to the end of its path and remain there, visible, so I can position the arrows properly?

Comment: In the slide, right click, and you can change the Layout.  Have one basic Layout A until the point you want and then change to a new Layout B and use after that point. That should work.

Comment: Why not animate the slide up to the point where the picture's moved to where you want it, dupe the slide, remove the existing animations, then add the arrows to the new slide?

Comment: @SteveRindsberg, I was hoping for a built-in PowerPoint feature, in ways of workarounds I think the accepted answer is better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is a brute-force method for creating the arrows in the right place:

- Animate the picture and let it go all the way to the end
- Take a screenshot of the slide
- [Insert it as the background picture on the slide](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/add-a-background-picture-to-slides-4b0b98d4-774c-4e08-9c38-e8c92f58c957)
  or
  [Insert the picture in PowerPoint](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/insert-a-picture-in-powerpoint-5f7368d2-ee94-4b94-a6f2-a663646a07e1),
  whichever is easier
- Create the arrows
- Delete the background picture.

The arrows will now be in the right place.

Comment: Alternatively, one could put a sticky note (y'know, a *physical* one, typically made of yellow paper) on the screen.   Maybe not as precise, but *a **lot*** quicker.

Comment: @Scott, I'd personally cringe and die if I see someone putting a sticky note on the actual screen. I dun knoe if it leaves a mark, but I'd be damned if I find out! :D

Comment: This, actually, isn't an answer to the question, more of a workaround, but seeing as PowerPoint is *severely more lacking* in features than I thought, I'll accept it.